# simple_navigation_goals no such file or directory

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to ROS. I am using ubuntu 16.04 and am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals#CA-f6095c746d404945145918ff6f075e6d465fdb85_1)

I followed all the steps, however when I run ./bin/simple_navigation_goals in the end, I get

bash: ./bin/simple_navigation_goals: No such file or directory

Can someone let me know why this is?

I have already tried to do source devel/setup.bash after I did catkin_make

Thanks,
Aaron

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293382/simple_navigation_goals-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 135 on 2018-06-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-06**:
I see that's how the tutorial that you linked to tells you to run the node way which I find strange. Usually, you'd run the node with

```
rosrun <package-name> <node-name>
```

Can you try running the node that way and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

figured it out, you have to cd in to /catkin_ws/devel/lib/simple_navigation_goals and then run ./simple_navigation_goals to work...

---

Originally posted by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) with karma: 135 on 2018-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-06**:
How did you compile the node and how are you trying to run it? You should be able to use `rosrun` from anywhere in your terminal (i.e., not having to be in `/catkin_ws/devel/lib/simple_navigation_goals` )

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-08**:
yes, you are correct. thank you!